# How did Kafka make the design decision to persist states in consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

1. It seems Kafka persist states in consumers. Does this affect the messaging delivery latency? If so, how the design decision is made?
2. Are there any mode that can choose to disable the state persistence and trade off for latency? If so, would this break the at-least-once semantics?

Comment: Consumers poll and fetch a batch of records, temporarily, yes, no it doesn't affect latency.  If you want to ask about design decisions, try joining the development mailing list... If you're not using transaction actions or idempotent properties the best you can do is at least once

Comment: Why "Consumers persist states" doesn't affect latency?

Comment: Latency of what? Polling messages happens fairly quickly, and depending on how state is actually stored, insertion into a key value store is usually fairly constant ,or O{1)

Comment: 1) When measuring the delivery latency, do you only measure from the Kafka cluster (brokers) received the messages and then send to the consumers? When the clients (hold the consumer, if I understand correctly) receive the message, there will be time spent at persisting the message if the message is stored before being processed, correct? 2) What about the push mode where brokers push messages to consumers

Comment: 2) Brokers never push messages, they are always polled 1) I would suggest measuring both delivery time and processing time separately. That way, you can tweak consumer settings or code independently to optimize them. Can you please link to the documentation where you've found consumers are persisting state, anyway ?

Comment: I've found it (consumers maintain the states by default) in a slideshare: https://www.slideshare.net/mumrah/kafka-talk-tri-hug/17 and https://photos.app.goo.gl/cy6q81AnAtjUXCnn7

Maybe it's the users' responsibility to maintain the received messages' state/backlog

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that slide is referring to. Consumers poll a batch of messages, sure, and that batch is what you loop over in your code. But that state isn't persisted between poll sessions within the consumer API

Comment: I also see this is referenced in the Kafka paper: https://snipboard.io/57L3Rh.jpg (http://notes.stephenholiday.com/Kafka.pdf) It also mentioned the states in consumers have retention policies. In most cases, the consumers will finish the backlog. But when the consumers have some unhealthy status, there might have message omissions. Make sense?

Comment: The *consumer **group*** maintains information about what has been read, not any individual consumer. That information is indeed stored in the broker in the `_consumer_offsets` topic. You may want to look at the Kafka wiki rather than 3rd party pdfs / slides https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Client-side+Assignment+Proposal